# Why are iPhone 5s UI elements not scaling on iPhone6?

Tags: ios, uibutton, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I understand that the native resolution for:

iPhone 5s: 320*568 points = 640*1136

iPhone 6:  375*667 points = 750*1334

They are both at 2x resolution.

Wouldn't that mean that if I have a UIButton of 202x43 (wxh) points in iPhone 5s and I run the app in iPhone 6, that same button should scale by 1.16 (375/320).

It is staying at 320*568 instead.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issue, 
Some views in iPhone 6 are not scaling properly (No launch screen added for iphone 6, +). Debugging I found some views I had 2 xibs one for 3.5 inches and 4 inches, I was loading the 3.5 inches views for the iphone 6 instead of the 4 inches xib.

Answer (score 0):

if your project have a 4.7" launch image, button will be 202X43; when no 4.7" launch image, button will be scale by 1.16.